# How can I add a loop?

Tags: c

I am doing a program that tells me which days is Holy Week but I don't know how to make a loop so that the years increase as far as the user says and I don't know how to make the user choose the columns and I don't know how to make them appear. I'm new using C

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main() {
      printf(Dia_pascua(2016));
  }

  int Dia_pascua(temporada) {
      int a,b,c,d,e,n,q;
      a= temporada % 19;
      b= temporada % 4;
      c= temporada % 7;
      d= (19 * a + 24) % 30;
      e= (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 5) % 7;
      n= (22 + d + e);

      if (n>31) {
          int inicio = n - 38;
          int dia = n - 31;
          printf("La semana santa inicia el %i de abril",inicio);
          printf("\nLa semana santa termina el %i de abril\n",dia);
      } else if (n<=31) {
          int inicio = n -7;
          printf("La semana santa inicia el %i de marzo\n",inicio);
          printf("nLa semana santa termina el %i de marzo\n",n);
      }
  }
```

Comment: loop what area ? here every statement is different

Comment: You also should know that c, c++ and c# are three totally different languages.please tag the relevant one only

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm for determining the "holy week?" I have no idea what even defines a "holy week."

Comment: Before learning loops, work out what language you are in

Comment: Why cant the post be edited?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I submitted an edit about 10 minutes ago that is awaiting peer review. This might be blocking further edits.

Answer (score 1):

> Looping C

```
int main() 
{ 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 
    printf( "Hello World\n"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Here we can apply loop

```
int main() 
{ 
    int i=0; 

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
    { 
        printf( "Hello World\n");     
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```